# What does the 8 sign mean?

Tags: piano

[image]

What does the 8 then dotted line mean? Starting from measure 9. Change of octave? Up or down?

Also the dotted line ends with a down turn? It turns sharply perpendicularly down. Does it mean one octave down?

Does it apply to only treble clef or both clefs?

Comment: May I ask what the piece is?

Comment: It's from a czerny piano exercise book

Answer (score 4):

In general, when there is an 8 and a dotted line above the treble clef, then you play the right hand an octave higher.

When there is an 8 and a dotted line below the bass clef, then you play the left hand an octave lower.

So in this case, you would play the right hand an octave higher until the sharp down line. This signifies the end of playing in a different octave.